# LibreOffice Automation - Update All

Tags: automation, controls, libreoffice, odt, tableofcontents

Is there a way to automate these steps?

- open a LibreOffice ODT
- update the TOC and other fields (e.g. via menu Tools|Update|Update All)
- save and close the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Windows, then this can be achieved very easily using [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/):

```
start("LibreOffice", r"c:\path\to\your\document.odt")
press(ALT + 't', 'u', 'u')
press(CTRL + 's')
press(ALT + F4)
```

You can save these 4 lines to a text file with the *.at* extension and play it back using [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) whenever required.

If you would like Automa to be able to find labels, click on menus etc. you need to go to **Tools|Options|LibreOffice|Accessibility** and tick the "*Support assistive technology tools (program restart required)*" checkbox. Then, for example the following will be possible:

```
start("LibreOffice", r"c:\path\to\your\document.odt")
click("Tools", "Update", "Update All")
press(CTRL + 's')
press(ALT + F4)
```

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com/) developers*